# lualatex (with fontspec) finds fonts only by font file name

Tags: luatex, fontspec, mactex, luaotfload

I cannot get lualatex (MacTeX2017, updated this morning) to use font names. It seems only to want to use font **file** names.

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% !TEX TS-program = LuaLaTeX

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

%% This works:
\setmainfont{GalliardPro-Roman}[%
    BoldFont=GalliardPro-Bold,
    ItalicFont=GalliardPro-Italic,
    BoldItalicFont=GalliardPro-BoldItalic]

%% This does not:   
%\setmainfont{ITC Galliard Pro Roman}

\begin{document}

Some text. \textbf{Some text.} \emph{Some Text.} \textbf{\emph{Some Text.}}

\end{document}
```

If I use the font name as the argument to `\setmainfont`, I get this error:

```
luaotfload | resolve : sequence of 3 lookups yielded nothing appropriate.

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
./mwe-lua.tex:15: fontspec error: "font-not-found"
! 
! The font "ITCGalliardProRoman" cannot be found.
! 
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  

l.15    \setmainfont{ITC Galliard Pro Roman}
```

I have put symlinks to the font files in ~/Library/Fonts and luaotfload-tool seems happy with that. However, looking at luaotfload-names.lua (from ~/Library/texlive/2017/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names) I note that `["plainname"]="GalliardPro-Roman"` is given for 'ITC Galliard Pro Roman', whereas in previous years (2015 for example) this is given as `["plainname"]="ITC Galliard Pro Roman"`

I have no substantive problem with using the font file name if I have to (though the `fontspec` documentation states that either the font name or the font file name can be used), but would rather have the convenience of using the font name instead.

Puzzled.

Comment: Can you reproduce with a font other people have?

Comment: Have you tried “ITC Galliard Pro,” without the “Roman”? That works for me with an up-to-date TeX Live on GNU/Linux.  `\setmainfont{ITC Galliard Pro}[Numbers={OldStyle,Proportional},StylisticSet=1]`

Comment: @Thérèse Spot on! That would seem to argue that the font's "family name" is used -- which makes sense. But some tests with other fonts (Monotype Centaur) don't confirm that, but a test with 'STIX Two Text' (https://sourceforge.net/projects/stixfonts/) seems to. Interesting. Thanks.

Comment: @cfr Not yet. For a while, I wondered if the font family name was being used, but that does not seem to be always the case. I will keep looking.

Comment: I think that I can confirm that luaotfload-tool/luatex now uses the **font family name** (in addition to the PostScript name) to select fonts. As I said, this is reasonable, but is this a change?

Comment: @Thérèse By the way, I was wrong about Centaur. I had neglected to run it through luaotfload-tool. It works if you use the **font family name**, just as with Galliard.